# Are there $5$ points in space such that, for $n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$, some pair of them have distance $n$?

Tags: geometry

> Do there exist $5 $ points in the space, such that for all $n \in \{1,2,3 \ldots , 10\}$ there exist two of them such that distance between them is $n$?

Hello everybody! I hope everyone is doing well. Can anybody help me to solve the problem above... It is an entirely new problem to me and I have never attempted such a problem before. I have no idea where to start..

I think the answer may be no.. because the triangle inequality is not satisfied by triplets like $1,2,3 $ etc. But I am really not sure.. Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me suppose that no $3$ points lie on one line.
Than there are 2 obsevations you need:

- There are exactly $10$ different distances between $5$ points, thus you already know them all (that's easy to check, so I do not elaborate)
- Consider the point that has edge length $1$ adjacent to it and prove that no other edge can be adjacent to this point (thus contradiction)

Let me elaborate on the latter.
consider the point that is adjacent to the edge length $1$.
Can the edge length $2$ be adjacent to this point as well?
Probably no, since any edge between points on the other ends of edges length $1$ and $2$ cannot be joined without violating the triangles inequality ($3$ is already too big, the rest numbers are even bigger).
Ok, can it be adjacent to the edge length $3$?
Probably no as well: you cannot connect the other ends by length $2$ edge (too small) and cannot connect them with length $4$ edge (already too long).
Proceding this way we can show that no edge can be ajacent to the point that is adjacent to the edge length $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5$ be five points in the space such that $$\big\{A_iA_j\,|\,i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}\text{ and }i\neq j\big\}=\{1,2,\ldots,10\}\,.\tag{*}$$
Suppose without loss of generality that $A_1A_2=1$.  For $i\in\{3,4,5\}$, we see from (*) that either $$A_1A_i\ge A_2A_i+1=A_2A_i+A_1A_2$$ or $$A_2A_i\geq A_1A_i+1=A_1A_i+A_1A_2\,.$$
By the Triangle Inequality, all $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_i$ must be on a line for each $i=3,4,5$.  Hence, all the five points are collinear.  Now, it should be easy to show that such a configuration on a line does not exist.

Indeed, if $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ are points in the space such that
$$\big\{A_iA_j\,|\,i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\text{ and }i\neq j\big\}=\left\{1,2,\ldots,\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right\}\,,$$
then $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ are collinear and $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  (The cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ are vacuous.)  For $n\in\{2,3,4\}$, there is a unique configuration up to isometry and permutation of points.

Comment: I think perhaps you meant $n\in\{1,2,3,4\}$?

Comment: No, I do mean $n\in\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Well, there is a solution for $n=4$, specifically $(0,0)(1,0)(4,0)(6,0)$

Comment: Ahh, I somehow missed this solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain this part: “Hence, all the five points are collinear. Now, it should be easy to show that such a configuration on a line does not exist.”

Comment: The problem reduces to whether there are five real numbers $a_1<a_2<a_3<a_4<a_5$ such that $$\left\{a_j-a_i\,|\,1\leq i <j\leq 5\right\}=\{1,2,\ldots,10\}\,.$$  You may set $a_1:=0$ and $a_5:=10$.